# VBA: How to loop through labels (not on a userform)?

Tags: vba, controls, ms-word

My Word document has many ActiveX labels. [Not textboxes: my original title was in error.]

I'd like a macro to loop through them to perform an action on each of them (changing the captions), but I don't know how to identify them.

If they were on a userform, I'd say:
 `For each aLabel in UserForm1.Controls`

But that doesn't apply in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is textboxes you're working with, per the title but not the question, the document's Shapes collection may be what you're after:

```
Sub ShapeLoop()

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ThisDocument.Shapes
        ' Test if shp is one you're interesed in, perhaps using shp.Name
        Debug.Print shp.Name
        ' Do Stuff
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Edit:

Same again for the fields collection

```
Sub FieldLoop()

    Dim fld As Field

    For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
        If TypeName(fld.OLEFormat.Object) = "Label" Then
            Debug.Print fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
            fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "New Caption"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I really did mean labels instead of textboxes. I tried your suggestion  just in case, but it doesn't capture labels.

Comment: OK, see update to my answer. You can use the Fields collection to get at the object, and check it's type for 'Label' and set the Caption etc.