# Iterate through ActiveX label with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, activex

I have a word document containing several sequential labels (ActiveX controls at the moment, open to suggestions, see image below), labelled as label1, label2, etc.

[image: Using 'legacy' ActiveX control label]

I want to use VBA to caption these labels using data from excel.

So far I have based my approach on this article, but want to add a loop to get each label captioned (I have about 40) without 40 lines of code.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/

The reason I am using ActiveX controls is because the tutorial suggested it. Since they are called 'legacy' I suppose there are better alternatives.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub LoadText1_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim cnt As Integer

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\...\content.xlsx")

For cnt = 1 To 40

    ThisDocument.ContentControls("label" & cnt).Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cnt, 1)

    'Alternative methods tried:
    ThisDocument.OLEObjects("label" & cnt).Object.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cnt, 1)
    ThisDocument.Controls("label" & cnt).Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cnt, 1)
    ThisDocument.Shapes("label" & cnt).OLEFormat.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cnt, 1)

Next cnt

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing
```

End Sub

I get the following error most of the time:

[image: Method or data member not found error]

I did try this, but it didn't work.

[VBA: How to loop through labels (not on a userform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114563/vba-how-to-loop-through-labels-not-on-a-userform)

[VBA ActiveX label in a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345275/vba-activex-label-in-a-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to loop through the ActiveX objects in the word document:

```
For Each AX_Controls In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If AX_Controls.OLEFormat.ProgID = "Forms.Label.1" Then
       MsgBox  AX_Controls.OLEFormat.Object.Name
    End If
Next AX_Controls
```

The example I have provided here prints out the label name but you could take it as an example and try to modify it as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following points while setting up this program.

- `Word VB Editor` in `Tools-References` to include Reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library corresponding to your version.
- It may happen during program setting that `Excel` instance is not properly closed then `Excel` file gets locked for editing. Either you save a new version of file and make corresponding changes in Word program or restart system to keep same program versions.
- The following code syntax for looping worked for me. Other variations of limiting `for loop` to limited number of fields did not work for me and gives rise to syntax error. You may try other variations if you like to.

  ```
  For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
  fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) & exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
  i = i + 1
  Next
  ```
- I kept Label names using sequence like Label1, Label2, Label3 etc.
- Even Command buttons captions get changed as per Excel worksheet cell references.
- I tried out on a sample of 5 Labels and program works fine as can be seen from the appended snapshot. I only worked on getting proper syntax to work and further improvements can be made for document looks and aesthetic measures for layout.

[image: iterate_activex_labels]

- This example code saved in expense2.docm file works for me:

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\mydirb\expenses2.xlsx") 'Change path as per your requirement
    i = 2
         For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
             fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) & exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
         i = i + 1
         Next
         For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
         Debug.Print fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
         Next

       exWb.Close
       Set exWb = Nothing

     End Sub
  ```